# Use Apple Watch as a handheld Keynote remote?

Tags: macos, ios, keynote, apple-watch

I have to give a 5-minute Keynote presentation from my MacBook Pro in a few days, and while I'd love to not carry my phone around as a remote, I'm also not a fan of the idea of tapping my wrist every time I need to change slides. Is there a way to use my Apple Watch as an always-awake Keynote remote that I can hold in my hand rather than needing to keep on my wrist?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up the iOS version of Keynote on your iPhone to be a remote control for Keynote on either another iOS device (such as your iPad) or your Mac. To do this, perform the following steps:

1. On the device that you'll be using to present from, open the remote control configuration:
   On iOS, this feature is located in Remote | Devices | Add a Device
   On OS X, this feature is located in Keynote | Preferences | Remotes (Ensure that the Enable checkbox is checked)
2. On the iPhone paired with the Apple Watch, open Keynote and select Remote | Devices | Add a Device
3. On the Mac or iOS device you'll be presenting from, select the Link button beside the remote device that you wish to use to control presentations
4. Verify the code shown on the screen, then complete the setup

Once this initial setup has been completed, open the Keynote app on your presenting device and begin a presentation.

On the Apple Watch, launch the Keynote app. Once the app launches, it will search and connect to the paired Mac or iOS device used for presentations. You'll get a Ready message (Figure A) when you're ready to control a presentation. When you see this message, it means that you can open the presentation on your Mac or iOS device that you'll be presenting.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-how-to-use-the-apple-watch-to-control-keynote-presentations/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the question was not about setting up the watch to use as a remote, but rather to use it in the hand instead of having to keep it on the wrist.  The watch will lock if not on the wrist so the OP is looking for a work around.